# Nested functions with recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, flood-fill

I've looked at a ton of references and have seen that C# supports nested functions through lambda, but I'm completely new to C# (and .NET for that matter). I want to write a flood-fill implementation, with the parameters of a parent function accessible to the nested child.

Here's what it should look like, ideally:

```
private void StartFloodFill(color,otherstuff,pixel)
{
      function Recursion(pixel,color)
      {
             do(otherstuff);
             //etc...
             Recursion(pixel,color);
      }
}
```

The `Recursion(pixel,color);` call is where my confusion lies. I can't access a reference to the function from inside the function.

I know there should be a workaround for this, but I don't know what that is. How can I implement a recursive function like that demonstrated above in C#?

Comment: A recursive delegate?

Comment: No idea. Can you explain?

Comment: Why did this get closed? It is a perfectly legit question and nothing is unclear about it. This idiom is used in functional programming all the time.

Comment: @BitTickler Meta: [Why was this old question closed when it was asked?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317703/why-was-this-old-question-closed-when-it-was-asked)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested, you can use a recursive delegate. Normally, you'd declare a delegate like this:

```
Func<int,int, int> = (a, b) => a+b;
```

Where [`Func<int, int, int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534647%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the type of a delegate that takes 2 ints, and returns another int.

But since you want to make it call itself, you have to declare the variable before assigning the delegate.

```
Func<Pixel, Color, SomeType> func = null;

func = (pixel, color) => {
    //do stuff...

    if(endCondition)
       return someTypeValue;
    else
       return func(pixel, color);
};
```

Comment: +1: Note that you don't have to assign function to variable - [Anonymous Recursion in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx)... But if you expect non-functional-programmers to read your code - declaring variable first ifs perfectly fine (and probably preferable, despite possibility of changing that variable inadvertently).